# How to get Email Details from magento 2 using preferences

Tags: magento2, email, preference

I need to get Email Details for recipients,Subject,body,header, so i wrote a preference to override a **Sendmail** class then, get email Details and follow my blow code:

di.xml FIle:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc /config.xsd">
     <!-- for override magento default Transport class with our custom module model-->
     <preference for="\Magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail.php" type="ChennaiBox\EmailType\Model\Sendmail.php"/>
</config>
```

And My **SmailMail** Class:

```
  <?php
#require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php';
class Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail extends Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract
{

public $subject = null;
public $parameters;
public $EOL = PHP_EOL;
protected $_errstr;

    public function __construct($parameters = null)
{
    if ($parameters instanceof Zend_Config) {
        $parameters = $parameters->toArray();
    }

    if (is_array($parameters)) {
        $parameters = implode(' ', $parameters);
    }

    $this->parameters = $parameters;
}



public function _sendMail()
{
    if ($this->parameters === null) {
        set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));

            **$rcp = $this->recipients,
            $sub = $this->_mail->getSubject(),
            $body= $this->body,
            $head= $this->header**

           **$myfile = fopen("SendMailFile1.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
           fwrite($myfile, "This is my Email Test");
           fwrite($myfile, $sub);
           fclose($myfile);**

    } else {
        if(!is_string($this->parameters)) {

            #require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception(
                'Parameters were set but are not a string'
            );
        }

        set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleMailErrors'));
           **$rcp = $this->recipients,
            $sub = $this->_mail->getSubject(),
            $body= $this->body,
            $head= $this->header**

           **$myfile = fopen("SendMailFile2.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
           fwrite($myfile, "This is my Email Test");
           fwrite($myfile, $sub);
           fclose($myfile);**

    }

    if ($this->_errstr !== null || !$result) {

        #require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception('Unable to send mail. ' . $this->_errstr);
    }
}
```

}

I try to Override this class and get Email details But, Its Working for Me, NO files created on this directory and no logs based on this process.but, Email Send perfectly. What is problem in my code and how to get email details while send a email to customer.

Comment: I reckon your class is not properly declared, can you change `class Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail extends Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract` to `class ChennaiBox_EmailType_Model_Sendmail extends Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail`

Comment: Hello @RaphaelatDigitalPianism   I follow your way but this also not working for me. magento 2 have any security, because yesterday i edit magento 2 code file this also not working. thanks for support